# Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'Library.donvidonhietdo.CelsiusSangFahrenheit(decimal)' has some invalid arguments 36 13 Test

Tags: c#

My code:

```
using System;
using Library;

namespace Test
 {
 /// <summary>
 /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    private void getFahrenheit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxCelsius);
        donvidonhietdo dv1 = new donvidonhietdo();
        dv1.CelsiusSangFahrenheit(textBoxCelsius);
    }
 }
} 
//WPF
```

My "Library"

```
public class donvidonhietdo
{
    public decimal CelsiusSangFahrenheit(decimal Celsius)
    {
        decimal Fahrenheit;
        Fahrenheit = 32.0m + (Celsius * 1.8m);
        return Fahrenheit;
    }
    public decimal FahrenheitSangCelsius(decimal Fahrenheit)
    {
        decimal Celsius;
        Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32.0m) / 1.8m;
        return Celsius;
    }
}
```

(Use VS2010)
It show "Error  2   The best overloaded method match for 'Library.donvidonhietdo.CelsiusSangFahrenheit(decimal)' has some invalid arguments"
How can I fix ?

Comment: If `textBoxCelsius` is an actual `TextBox` control, you're obviously not passing the `decimal` parameter that method is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
decimal myDec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxCelsius.Text);
...
dv1.CelsiusSangFahrenheit(myDec);
```

You must use the .Text property from the TextBox and you must use the output from Convert.ToDecimal because it does not change the TextBox.Text.

Comment: and CelsiusSangFahrenheit expects a decimal, not a string or a TextBox. It will not convert automatically